# Uninitialized string offset: 1 on Yii2 View

Tags: php, yii2

i have this Uninitialized string offset :1 on Yii 2 like this

```
if($i>0){
        date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string(" ".($model->Lama*$i)." minutes"));
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$i</td>
            <td>$JamMasuk</td>
            <td>".date_format($date,"H:i")."</td>
            <td>".
            (
                \app\models\Absen::GroupTot($model->Id)[$i]?
                Html::a(\app\models\Absen::GroupTot($model->Id)[$i],
                ['view','id'=>$model->Id,'s'=>$i],['class'=>'btn btn-primary']):0
            )
            ."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
        $JamMasuk=date_format($date,"H:i");
    }
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: On which line this error is appended?

Comment: (
                \app\models\Absen::GroupTot($model->Id)[$i]?
                Html::a(\app\models\Absen::GroupTot($model->Id)[$i],
                ['view','id'=>$model->Id,'s'=>$i],['class'=>'btn btn-primary']):0
            )

Comment: Use `var_dump($model->Id); exit;` and check what is given. You can also send me in here (better is to use http://pastebin.com/ since the text will be big).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If did not return an error in your model;
change line:

```
\app\models\Absen::GroupTot($model->Id)[$i]?
```

with

```
isset(\app\models\Absen::GroupTot($model->Id)[$i])?
```